# Can't find CVS in import options in new Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I was using **Luna** and now thinking about an upgrade to **Mars**.
I can't find the CVS option in Import which was available in Luna by default.

Did they remove it in **Mars**.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on which package you downloaded, yes, the CVS support was not included. It should still be in the Mars Update Site, though.

Comment: thanks for your response. Do you know about any particular reason for not including cvs in new eclipse .?

Comment: @Saif CVS is very old and not really recommended these days.

Comment: I would say that it's just that someone using Eclipse vs. a packaged product built on it is more likely to want Git support included than CVS, including the people working on Eclipse itself since CVS has been deprecated in the eclipse.org infrastructure. An individual package page should be able to give you a detailed list of which Features are included, helping you find whether CVS support is in there or not.

Comment: @Saif - did you succeed installing the CVS integration? Because I installed it in my Mars.2 and it's not working (there's nothing in the projects' Team submenu)..

Comment: Yes i was able to integrate and serving my basic purpose. Cant be sure about Team submenu either I don't get what it's mean or may be I never needed that.

Comment: @Saif - can you tell me how? I just install CVS integration from the Eclipse marketplace and this used to work with the previous versions. I didn't really understand the accepted answer and the aprt with Mars Update Site. Thanks in advance

Comment: after your comment I tried to integrate "CVS Integration 1.4" with "Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)" and working well and also working well with Luna and Mars.1. Don't know what you problem is. really sorry that I could not help.

Comment: @Saif - I see, still thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 7):

The CVS Integration was removed by Eclipse consensus, because of the low usage rate of CVS, which is about 3.7%.

You can reference the URL below:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438297
- https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg10790.html

Also, if you want to install the CVS Integration, you can

- Click the "Help" at the top of Eclipse Mars.
- Choose "Eclipse Marketplace" option.
- Search the CVS Integration in "Find" search box.
- Finally, click the "Install" under the **CVS Integration item**.

Then I think you can use the CVS integration feature.

Comment: Now this might be obvious, but just in case it is not: if you use Eclipse CVS client , you need to invoke "Team -> Share Project" to get started.

Answer (score 5):

### Eclipse 2018

CVS integration has been dropped from default Eclipse installation **as well** as the Eclipse Marketplace!

Please use the oxygen-update-site to recover the CVS integration.

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen
```

Guide to install CVS integration on Eclipse 2018-12

1. Start Eclipse
2. If CVS integration is available stop here.
3. Click on Menu-point <kbd>Help</kbd> > <kbd>Install New Software ...</kbd>
4. Click to <kbd>Add...</kbd>
5. Use `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen` for name and location, press <kbd>OK</kbd>.
6. Change `type filter text` to `cvs` and check `Eclipse CVS Client`.
7. Hit <kbd>Finish</kbd>